# How to disable android.settings.CAST_SETTINGS option programmatically

Tags: android

How to disable cast setting option programmatically, as I enabled my application cast to my tv now I want to disable cast from tv at the time of kill app.

```java
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.CAST_SETTINGS"));
```

using these line I enabled

Comment: Please help me anybody, i am stuck at this point

Answer (score 0):

follow link [On Android, how to check the phone screen is casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75171643/on-android-how-to-check-the-phone-screen-is-casting) to check if the device is casting.
To disconnect, use:
var mediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(this)
mediaRouter.unselect(MediaRouter.UNSELECT_REASON_UNKNOWN)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35402478)